# Execute lambda in the context of another object

Tags: ruby

It seems like proc can be executed in another object but lambda cannot.

```
[1] pry(main)> class A; def a; 5; end; end
[2] pry(main)> pr = proc { a + 1 } # => #<Proc:0x007f5024264668@(pry):2>
[3] pry(main)> la = -> { a + 1 }   # => #<Proc:0x007f5023fc0e48@(pry):3 (lambda)>
[4] pry(main)> A.new.instance_eval &pr
=> 6
[5] pry(main)> A.new.instance_eval &la
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
from (pry):3:in `block in __pry__'
[6] pry(main)>
```

Is there any other way for lambda to be executed like proc in this example, or should I always use procs instead in the situations like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is that the receiver of `instance_eval` is passed to the block as an argument. Procs allow for undeclared arguments, lambdas do not.

```
pr = proc {|*args| p args; a + 1 }
A.new.instance_eval &pr
[#<A:0x43668596>]
 => 6
```

If you declare your lambda such that it receives an argument, it works just fine:

```
> la = ->(recv) { a + 1 }
> A.new.instance_eval &la
 => 6
```

You could just (and probably want to) use `instance_exec` instead though:

```
> la = -> { a + 1 }
> A.new.instance_exec &la
  => 6
> la = ->(add) { a + 1 + add }
> A.new.instance_exec 10, &la
  => 16
```